# Memory Leak Detection in DLLs

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I use third party DLL's in my java application to access native methods written in C. My application often gets crashed with malloc failed or out of swap space error message. There is no memory leak in my java application (Verified with profilers). Now I doubt that memory leak in third party DLL's. Is there any way to find out leak in DLL's.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a C/C++ tool to detect memory leaks in my dlls several months ago:

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8448/Memory-Leak-Detection

And you also have:

> http://vld.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

my first choice to detect memory issues is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). with java and JIT it might however not always work. 
but still worth to give it a shot. try running

```
valgrind --smc-check=all --trace-children=yes --show-reachable=yes --leak-check=full [your command]
```

cheers,